# Behavior of AVR microcontroller only containing bootloader

Tags: microcontroller, avr, bootloader

I'm working on an implementation of AVR109, where the bootloader times out after two seconds if a given series of bytes aren't received on the serial port, and then starts the main application using a function pointer to address 0.

The bootloader is working fine, and I'm able to program the AVR via serial port.  But when the AVR only contains the bootloader, and the flash memory at location 0 is empty, it takes two seconds in addition to the bootloader timeout every time the AVR restarts.  Why isn't this instantaneous?  Why isn't the AVR resetting immediately when the bootloader sets the pointer to an empty area in the flash?  Is this something I can configure?

**EDIT:** My bootloader conundrum actually proved to be caused by [PEBCAK](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PEBCAK).  An error in the initial timing loop in the bootloader caused the extra two second delay, and was fixed.  When jumping to the start of a blank/erased flash memory, it actually only took a few milliseconds before the bootloader started up again, i.e. not a big problem.  **But** the best approach is to check the flash memory location before jumping there.  If it's erased, just restart the bootloader instead of jumping to the empty area.

Comment: There is no such thing as "empty". There is some data that will be executed.

Comment: Didn't you just said it is using these 2 seconds to allow you to program it?

Comment: @EugeneSh. "it takes two seconds in addition to the bootloader timeout every time the AVR restarts."  In other words it takes four seconds when the bootloader timeout is set to two seconds.

So when the pointer is set to address 0, which I assume is all 0xFF after the flash is erased prior to programming the bootloader, it resets after exactly two seconds.  And then takes an additional two seconds to time out again.

And so it goes in a four second cycle.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Even when the flash is erased prior to the bootloader being programmed?  Isn't the flash set to 0xFF then?  What happens when the AVR tries to execute 0xFF?

Comment: @Oystein: Unless by "erase" you mean "rip off with a pair of pliers", it contains some data. 0xFF is data too.

Comment: Do you have the source code for the bootloader?

Comment: @PlasmaHH You're stating the obvious. I'm asking what happens when the bootloader, residing in the far end of the flash memory, orders the instruction pointer to the beginning of the flash memory, which is erased.  Why does it take two seconds from this happening to the bootloader starting up again?  Is anything controlling this behavior that I can configure?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, it's based on AVR109, so I have access to the source code.  The bootloader's just running in a while loop for two seconds before calling a function pointer set to address 0 (which is empty).  But it takes an additional two seconds for the bootloader to start up again, and my question is why this is.

Comment: Do you have any debugging capabilities?

Comment: Where the "main application" is sitting in the flash? What is the instruction clock frequency?

Comment: @EugeneSh. No, unfortunately I don't have debugging capabilities currently.  The main application is starting at address 0.  Instruction clock frequency?  The AVR is running on a 16MHz external crystal, if that's what you mean..?

Comment: Wait.. So I didn't get the question. Do you mean that once you have it erased, it will give you 4 second to program? Where the bootloader is sitting? How does it know it has to jump to bootloader address at the startup?

Comment: It probably takes two seconds for it to execute every unknown instruction in the flash and get back to the start of the bootloader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the answer its to the behavior of the system is "who knows" because you basically have an undefined behavior because there is nothing written to flash to the MCU will try to use whatever is at address 0 as the reset vector for the application, if is erased it will try to use 0xffff and I do not think that the AVR issues an exception when you go outside the memory bounds and it will execute some random instruction and probably hang in there until the watchdog or other invalid instruction causes a reset. Most boot loaders tend to do a check for the value at the reset vector (typically address 0) to verify it is not blank and if it is they just loop the boot loader indefinitely to prevent the MCU to run into undefined behavior.

Comment: +1. Indeed, AVRs will just execute instructions [no matter what](http://atmel.force.com/support/articles/en_US/FAQ/Jump-to-invalid-instruction-in-AVR).

Comment: +1 @TomCarpenter Thanks for information about AVR just running through memory locations until it hits a valid instruction.  And for information on "proper" bootloader behavior (that it should check memory at location 0 before jumping there).